# Querying for Perm Set

Tags: apex, soql, community, query

I would like to query to see if a user has a permission set. I want to return the response as Boolean value.

Current Code:

```
public static Boolean returnUserPermIds(){
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissionSetAssignments = [SELECT PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment where PermissionSetId = '0PSq00000001rt9GAA'];
    List<ID> permissionSetIds = new List<ID>();
    for(PermissionSetAssignment assignment: permissionSetAssignments){
        permissionSetIds.add(assignment.PermissionSetId);
    }
    return permissionSetIds.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your overall objective is. You may be able to, for example, replace this query with a `FeatureManagement` check for a Custom Permission, which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Do you specifically care about a Permission *Set*? It would be a lot easier if you just used a `Custom Permission` at which point you could simply check `FeatureManagement.checkPermissions('MyCustomPermission')`.

Comment: Adrian, well the permission set allows a user to access a link through clicking on a number. Would you think in the scenario of checking for a users permission I should go by using a Custom Permission over a Permission Set?

Answer (score 2):

You're basically there.

What you're doing now is returning a list of `PermissionSetAssignment`.

You want to return a `boolean`.

Since your query is so specific (*either there is or there isn't a value*), you can simply add this to your return statement

```
return !userPermSets.isEmpty();
```

You can see this method in the [List Class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm). You're checking if the list is null (true), which means there's no permission set. However, since you're looking for whether the user has it or not (if it's null, then it's `false`), you add the `!` to inverse the result.

---

Edit:

As you're having issues, the easy way to test is to run the following script in anonymous apex in Dev Console

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> permAssign = [SELECT ID From PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Assignee.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND PermissionSetId = ''];
System.debug('results of query return ' + permAssign);
System.debug('testing true/false ' + !permAssign.isEmpty());
```

Make sure to add a PermissionSetID you know is assigned to yourself into the script above. This runs fine for me in my org. You can select "open log" in the bottom right before executing and then filter the log for "debug only".

[image]

Make sure you're looking at the correct log, the tab in dev console will say the time and executeAnonymous

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104505/discussion-on-answer-by-kris-goncalves-querying-for-perm-set).